# List files in multiline textbox while executing from remote desktop

Tags: nsis

I have tried to list the sql files in NSIS page as :

```
 ${NSD_CreateListboxMultiselect} 10 30 440 250 ""
    Pop $sql_job_file_list
    ToolTips::Modern $sql_job_file_list 1 "List of files" " "   

    FindFirst $R0 $R1 "D:\folder\*.sql" 
    Loop_jobs:
        IfErrors Loop_jobs_end
            ${NSD_LB_AddString} $sql_job_file_list "$R1"
            ${SQLjobsListArray->Push} "$R1" ;used for default selection of listbox
        FindNext $R0 $R1
        IfErrors 0 Loop_jobs
    Loop_jobs_end:
```

It works fine but while executing from remote desktop, no files is listed as the folder path structure are correct as that of working in local computer.

I am looking for how to handle the nsis application in remote desktop ??

Comment: Is "D:\folder\*.sql" actually hardcoded in your application?

Answer (score 0):

Remote Desktop should not matter, are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: Thanks for reply, well the loop get halted by IfErrors code, while i have added ClearErrors at top of the code, it works, as in local it is optional to include clearErrors